# How do we copy an entire directory to another directory in maven?

Tags: copy, maven, build-automation, weblogic

I would like to improve the build foe development in our project and in this regard I would like to achive the following using maven:

1. I want to copy an entire directory heirarchy, including the directory itself to another directory using maven. How do I achive that ?
   I need this to copy a "MyApp.ear" directory to \domain\autodeploy.
2. Then, I would like to create a file "REDEPLOY" under autodeploy of weblogic domain using maven
3. When ever we do some changes to java file, would like to copy only the exploded dir of class files and touch the REDEPLOY filr using maven to trigger the auto-deploy

Pls. suggest how do we achive this using maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple suggestions come to mind:

- The [maven antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) will let you copy files, folders, etc
- The [maven deploy plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) allows for uploading with ftp & ssh - and so does the antrun plugin